# How to display name instead of ID in Rails 3.2 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am implementing a library and there is a table for categories.

the categories table is as follows:-

```
 id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  parent_cat_id integer DEFAULT 0,
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT categories_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Now the problem I am facing is that i want to display the name of the category instead of id of the category which is referencing.

My index.html.erb file is as follows:-

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Parent Category Id</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>

<% @categories.each do |c| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= c.id %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.name %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.parent_cat_id %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => c.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', {:action => 'delete', :id => c.id},
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this value?" } %></td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
```

Is there any way I can implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following in your category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: :parent_cat_id
end
```

Then you can just do the following

```
<td><%= c.parent_category.name if c.parent_category %>&nbsp;</td>
```

I added `if` just to be sure that no error is raised if the category has no parent category

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
<td><%= c.parent_cat_id.name %>&nbsp;</td>
```

It works if your models are in relation.

Comment: Parent category id and category are in the same table

Comment: That is there is no foreign key references for the tables